# C++ - Templates, Linked Lists and Classes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have to write a C++ program that uses three data structures (one of them being linked lists). The program will ultimately have to read in data from a CSV, allow the user to add info to the CSV and allow people to search for data in the CSV.

I am trying to create a Patient Class that will take data in the CSV file, store each row of data into a Patient object and then link those objects via a linked list.

Everything seemed to be coming together fine, but when I build I get the following error messages:

Build started: Project: Project25, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  PatientTest.cpp
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project25\project25\patienttest.cpp(75): error C2955: 'PatientType' : use of class template requires template argument list

1>          c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project25\project25\patienttest.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'PatientType'

1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project25\project25\patienttest.cpp(75): error C2133: 'plist' : unknown size

1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project25\project25\patienttest.cpp(75): error C2512: 'PatientType' : no appropriate default constructor available

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include <cassert> 

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
struct Node
{
    Type info;
    Node<Type> *next;
};

template <class Type>
class PatientType
{
public:
    //Constructors
    PatientType();
    PatientType(string patientSSN, string patientFName, string patientLName, string patientEmail, string patientNumber);

    //Accessors
    string getPSSN();
    string getPFName();
    string getPLName();
    string getPEmail();
    string getPNumber();

    //Mutators
    void setPSSN(string newPSSN);
    void setPFName(string newPFName);
    void setPLName(string newPLName);
    void setPEmail(string newPEmail);
    void setPNumber(string newPNumber);

    void print();

    void loadList(Node<Type>);

private:
    int length;
    Node<Type>* head;

    string pSSN;
    string pFName;
    string pLName;
    string pEmail;
    string pNumber;
};

template <class Type>
PatientType<Type>::PatientType()
{
    pSSN = "SSN";
    pFName = "First Name";
    pLName = "Last Name";
    pEmail = "Email";
    pNumber = "Phone Number";
}
template <class Type>
PatientType<Type>::PatientType(string patientSSN, string patientFName, string patientLName, string patientEmail, string patientNumber)
{
    pSSN = patientSSN;
    pFName = patientFName;
    pLName = patientLName;
    pEmail = patientEmail;
    pNumber = patientNumber;
}


int main()
{

    PatientType plist;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Update - I tried doing `PatientType<PatientType> pList;`
Got the following error:
'PatientType' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Type', expected a real type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over how the code in the question uses `PatientType`, it seems `PatientType` does not need to be a template at all. It does not use any templated behaviour except for `Node<Type> * head;` and a function call that adds more `Node<Type>`s.

My first thought is to remove the template from `PatientType`, but this does not address the design mistake that got you to this point: You have conflated the patient with the list. The more limited in scope you can keep the responsibilities of an object, the better both conceptually (a patient is a patient, not a list of patients) and for maintenance and debugging. This touches on the fundamental Object Oriented Programming concepts of Encapsulation and Coupling and is likely at least two of the things you are expected to learn and demonstrate with this assignment.

If this is not an assignment, stand on the shoulders of giants and use `std::list` rather than rolling your own linked list.

Carrying on with the assumption that this is indeed an assignment for educational purposes, remove all list-like behaviour from `PatientType` and make a third class which is a Linked List Manager.

In this alternative `PatientType` does nothing but manage a single patient, `Node` does nothing but allow patients to be linked together, and `LinkedList` does nothing but link nodes of patients. Every structure is as simple and ignorant as possible. `PatientType` knows nothing about `Node`s and `LinkedList`s. Through the magic of templates, `Node` and `LinkedList` know nothing about `PatientType`. `Node` knows nothing about `LinkedList`, but `LinkedList` knows everything about `Node` because it's `LinkedLists`'s job to know `Node`s. Some coupling is unavoidable.

```
template <class Type>
struct Node
{
    Type info;
    Node<Type> *next;
};
```

Node is unchanged.

```
template <class Type>
class LinkedList
{
    Node<Type> *head;
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList&); // required by the Rule of Three
    ~LinkedList();
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList&); // required by the Rule of Three
    void insert(const Type&);
    void remove(const Type&);
    void print(std::ostream &);
    // other functions as required
};
```

Note how the user of `LinkedList` needs to know nothing about `Node` for this simple example. All they know is they have a `LinkedList` and it holds stuff for them. Also note I've left out how to find something in the list. That's tricky as heck, but it needs to wait until after you can add things to and and remove things from the list and successfully print it.

Recommendations: Start with a list of `int`s and make sure you can do everything you need to be able to do to with patients to a list of `int` before proceeding to a list of patients because it is a lot easier to test with something simple.

You will have to do a lot of testing of the list before adding any difficulty that is not immediately necessary. Linked Lists are a weeding assignment and require you to understand a lot of different material to execute. Practically no one working on their own gets it right the first few times.

Draw pictures to help visualize the list.

```
class PatientType
{
public:
    // public stuff that has no bearing on this example
    // void loadList(Node<PatientType>); eliminated
private:
    // Node<PatientType>* head; eliminated

    // private stuff that has no bearing on this example
};
```

`PatientType` lost all knowledge of `Node`s and the linking of `Node`s.

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList<PatientType> list;
    list.insert(PatientType(/*parameters*/))
}
```

Now you can independently work on all of the parts testing them separately. Put nothing together until you know it works properly separately. Bugs magnify the difficulty of finding and resolving any one bug as they add up, so the fewer bugs you face at any one time, the better.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate your template you need to provide the template type, for example

```
PatientType<int> plist;
```

Comment: so I tried doing PatientType<PatientType> pList but got this error message: 'PatientType' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Type', expected a real type

Comment: @LIStudent1234 `PatientType<PatientType>` looks suspiciously like you are trying to instantiate a template around itself. Think on the nature of recursion. Also think on whether or not `PatientType` should be a template at all. Perhaps `Node<PatientType>` is more along the lines of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your program would work much better if `PatientType` wasn't a template and you directly used the type in the

```
Node<PatientType>* head;
```

so you get

```
Node<PatientType>* head;
```

As this is C++ you could use `std::list` instead of playing a Game of Pointers, unless that's part of an assignment.